# Messages в Django при редиректе

Tags: python, django

Вот банальный код.

```
def func(request):
    messages.info(request, "Не покажется")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register/')

def func_2(request):    
    messages.info(request, "Все работает")
    return render_to_response('order.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

В def func_2 покажется страница, и выведется сообщение "Все работает". В def func произойдет редирект, при этом никакого сообщения не выведется.

Подскажите как передавать сообщения при редиректах?

В настройках:

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.messages',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно работать.

Напишите тесты. Убедитесь, что в хранилище messages попадает новая запись. Убедитесь, что записи из messages выводятся на странице регистрации.

Еще проверьте: по-моему, is_authenticated это метод, поэтому он (не результат его вызова, а сам метод) всегда not False.

Comment: Суть не в is_authenticated. Это было для примера. Сейчас упрощу код. Суть в том что когда request передаётся, то и message тянется, а если редиректит, то видимо с недостачей request и message пропадает.

На всех страницах сообщения выводятся, кроме страниц на которые были редиректы.

Вот интересно как это обойти.

Comment: Я почти всегда использую их с редиректом, и все работает. Посмотрите, что приходит в http 302 response браузеру. Возможно, виноват FallbackStorage, и стоит выбрать другой.

Comment: Спасибо за намек. Ведь точно, у меня message выводятся через js и именно тут я его не инициализировал. Все заработало. На столько был убежден что это не возможно и нужно искать другой метод, что банально на наличие ошибок не глянул.